# hyperlink click event not working on google chrome 37.0.2062.120

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

my website developed using asp.net mvc 4.0. page navigation done by loading the html in background (using iframe). here is the process:

1. Normal page load performed
2. All hyperlink bound its click handler to perform background loading
3. when a hyperlink clicked an iframe created using appropriate hyperlink url
4. when iframe page loaded its content appended to the main page
5. repeat step 2

step 1 through step 4 was fine but step 5, after step 5 when an hyperlink clicked instead of doing background loading the whole page loaded, so this is mean after the page loaded by iframe jquery fail to bind the click event of hyperlink.

this problem only occur on the latest google chrome version 37.0.2062.120 it is working fine on firefox and ie 10. i even install old version of google chrome (version 36.0.1985.143) and everything is working fine.

i know i could report an issue on the google chrome bug list. but i can't wait my site error until google fix this bug.

so is there a way to fix this issue or is there a trick to trace why the click event handler is not properly dispatched?

site spec:
- asp.net mvc 4
- jquery 1.7.2

**EDIT**

i manage to create simple code to mimic my problem here: http://ktutnik.com/index.html

so when user click any hyperlink the 'test.html' content will automatically appended to the body.

`index.html`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            bindHyperlinks($('body'));;
        });

        function bindHyperlinks(root) {
            root.find('a').click(function () {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                loadPage(url, function (html) {
                    $('body').append(html);
                    bindHyperlinks(html);
                });
                return false;
            });
        }

        function loadPage(url, cb) {
            var frame = $('<iframe/>');
            frame.hide();
            $('body').append(frame);
            frame.load(function () {
                var content = $(this).contents().find('body').children();
                cb(content);
                frame.remove();
            });
            frame.attr('src', url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/test.html">Load page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`test.html`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="/test.html">Go to test</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to analyze the issue without seeing relevant code. **Note**: Do you use adblock or any other similar extension? Try 'n disable those.

Comment: @ktutnik : It would be great if you create any sample demo for it.

Comment: @urbz no i don't use any adblock i tested on several machine with different configuration it still act the same. i will try to create the sample demo i hope i can mimic the problem.

Comment: i updated the thread and provide example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it is the **correct way to do** - answer but it solve my problem

on the iframe load event instead of

```
var content = $(this).contents().find('body').children();
cb(content);
```

i used

```
var content = $(this).contents().find('body').html();
cb($(content));
```

technically they have the same meaning, weird but its work!

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to know for certain without a code snippet.

A couple things you want to check are:

- Make sure you are returning false from the event handler.
- Make sure that you have removed the event handler before adding the new one ( e.g. `$("#myElement").off("click").on("click", function(e) {});`

I frames my not be the way to go however, using jQuery you can use a `$.get` to download the content of the page then embed it on the page, alternatively (and what I would recommend) you can use something like [Sammy](http://blog.apterainc.com/bid/313071/Turn-your-ASP-NET-MVC-app-into-a-Single-Page-Application-with-one-classy-Sammy-js-route) to handle the roughing for you.

Comment: thank you for your response, i updated the tread with a code example.